# Why does fstream causes segmentation fault when opening file with format?

Tags: c++, fstream

I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream asmfile("asmcode",ifstream::in);

  if(!asmfile)
  {
     cout << "error" << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

where "asmcode" is just a text file that exists in the same directory as the main file. It's literally an empty file that's created via bash ">dummy.txt".

I'm running this on Ubuntu Linux 18.04, using g++ 9.2.1 as a compiler.

This prints "error" in my machine. I have no clue why the file is not getting opened. I also noticed if I append the file format after the file name, I get a segmentation fault which is even more weird.

What is wrong here?

Comment: What is the current working directory when running this code?

Comment: @PaulSanders within a folder at the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the file extension, otherwise the program can not make a difference between 2 files with the same name.

`ifstream asmfile("asmcode.txt", ifstream::in);`